# Neo4j - charting data

Tags: neo4j

What is the best way to visualize neo4j data in a chart? I am looking for something simple just bar, line a pie charts. Not necessarily using the api but that would be ok too. Thank you

Comment: off-topic. Suggesting resources is not the purpose here. SO is more a place where you come *after* you have tried to visualise your neo4j data.

Comment: try quora or reddit for this. That will work much better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try https://github.com/jexp/spoon-neo4j library. It augments Neo4j browser to allow to draw pie, line charts etc...